# why rejected promises prints last ? it should be the second right?

Tags: javascript

this question i asked AI about it to rate my knowledge
my answer is
Resolved: A
Rejected: B
Resolved: C
, but when i ran it on nodejs runtime env and even browser it outputs
Resolved: A
Resolved: C
Rejected: B

```
function* generatorFunction() {
  yield Promise.resolve("A");
  yield Promise.reject("B");
  yield Promise.resolve("C");
}

const generator = generatorFunction();

for (const promise of generator) {
  promise
    .then((value) => console.log("Resolved:", value))
    .catch((error) => console.log("Rejected:", error));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is placing the `catch` handler on the promise returned from `.then()`, not the original promise. If you attach them both to the original promise, you get the sequence you expect:

```
for (const promise of generator) {
  promise.then((value) => console.log("Resolved:", value));
  promise.catch((error) => console.log("Rejected:", error));
}
```

You'll also get an unhandled rejection error from the first promise chain (the `.then()` chain. To deal with that, you can put a dummy catch on that one:

```
for (const promise of generator) {
  promise.then((value) => console.log("Resolved:", value)).catch(_ => _);
  promise.catch((error) => console.log("Rejected:", error));
}
```

It's a little clearer using `await` (well to me it is):

```
(async () => {
for (const promise of generator) {
  try {
    console.log("Resolved:", await promise);
  }
  catch(e) {
    console.log("Rejected:", e);
  }
}})()
```

*edit* — Bergi points out that the original problem could also be solved by assigning both the resolved handler and the rejection handler in the original `.then()` call:

```
for (const promise of generator) {
  promise.then(
    (value) => console.log("Resolved:", value), // happy
    (error) => console.log("Rejected:", error)  // not happy
  );
}
```

Comment: "*To deal with that, you can put a dummy catch on that one*" - no, just use [`.then(…, …)` instead of `.then(…).catch(…)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289/1048572)!

Comment: @Bergi sure, that'd work of course. I still think it's much clearer with `await`. *edit* oh wait, you mean that solves the original problem. Yes, yes it does. I'll update the answer.

Comment: That solves both the original problem and is also a better solution to avoid the unhandled rejection when branching `.…then();`

Answer (score 1):

Your `.then()` and `.catch()` calls are adding functions to the [event loop](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-event-loop/). Each time your loop gets the generator further, a new `Promise` is either resolved or rejected, that is, a function is added to the event loop. But, since the `.catch` is chained to the `.then`, which is also a promise and adds a function to the event loop because of the catch as well. Therefore, the event loop reached the `.then()` of B first which added a function to the event loop and this second function is executed *after* the `.then()` functions of A and C. You can use the fact that you can pass the `resolve` handler as the first parameter and the `reject` handler as the second parameter to the `.then()` call to your advantage:

```js
function* generatorFunction() {
  yield Promise.resolve("A");
  yield Promise.reject("B");
  yield Promise.resolve("C");
}

const generator = generatorFunction();

for (const promise of generator) {
  promise
    .then((value) => console.log("Resolved:", value), (error) => console.log("Rejected:", error));
}
```